# Float:right element not inline with float:left element

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a title `#resourceWrapTitle` that is being displayed in a rotated manner. One aspect I am using for positioning is `float:left`. When I do this, it makes my container to the right's position display somewhat downward from the top of where I am wanting it - container `#resourceCont`. I have this container set to `float:right`, so I thought it would appear right next to the title.

Does anyone know why the `#resourceCont` is being pushed down and how I can fix it?

Img of where I am wanting the container:

[image]

```css
#pdfBannerRight {
 width: 300px;
 background: #2f2f2f;
 height: 450px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 18%;
 right: 0;
}
#pdfBannerRightCont {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#resourceWrapTitle {
 float: left;
    transform-origin: top left;
 margin: 3% 0 0 8px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}
#resourceWrapTitle:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 height: 4px;
 background: #FFF;
 width: 80%;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 10px auto;
}
#pdfResourceWrap {
 float: right;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px 0;
 width: 80%;
 height: auto;
}
.pdfResource {
 width: 48%;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: 15px 1%;
 padding: 5px 0;
 text-align: center;
 -webkit-transition: all .45s ease;transition: all .45s ease;
}
.pdfResource:hover {
 background: gray;
 -webkit-transition: all .45s ease;transition: all .45s ease;
}
.pdfResource img {
 width: 50px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.resourceTitle {
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 font-size: .8rem;
 letter-spacing: .1rem;
 color: #F2F2F2;
 margin-top: 5px;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pdfBannerRight">
      <div id="pdfBannerRightCont">
       <h3 id="resourceWrapTitle">Resources</h3>
       <div id="pdfResourceWrap">
        
        <div id="resourceCont">
         <a href="#" class="pdfResource">
          <img src="https://imagineacademy.microsoft.com/content/images/microsoft-img.png" alt="Img 1">
          <h4 class="resourceTitle">Img 1</h4>
         </a><a href="#" class="pdfResource">
          <img src="https://imagineacademy.microsoft.com/content/images/microsoft-img.png" alt="Img2">
          <h4 class="resourceTitle">Img 2</h4>
         </a>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: there's several way to fix this. You can do it using flexbox or grid. Can you create jsFiddle or codeopen?

Comment: Just add position absolute to your #resourceWrapTitle

Comment: Jsfiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/ur670bjs/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

changes that I have made:

FROM

```
#resourceWrapTitle {
    float: left;
}
```

TO

```
#resourceWrapTitle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
```

The Reason why #pdfResourceWrap is not placing itself at the top is, #resourceWrapTitle is still at the top. Its rotated but its still in the flow of the document, holding its original place. But when I removed float from it and gave it an `absolute` position, its out of the flow of the document, thus not holding its original place. read [css box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model) and [css position](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/p/position/) if you are still not clear.

Hope that helps. Thanks.

```css
#pdfBannerRight {
 width: 300px;
 background: #2f2f2f;
 height: 450px;
 position: absolute;
 top: 18%;
 right: 0;
}
#pdfBannerRightCont {
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
#resourceWrapTitle {
 position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform-origin: top left;
 margin: 3% 0 0 8px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
    transform: rotate(-90deg) translateX(-100%);
    font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
    letter-spacing: .2rem;
    font-size: 1.7rem;
    color: #FFF;
    text-transform: uppercase;

}
#resourceWrapTitle:after {
 content: '';
 display: block;
 height: 4px;
 background: #FFF;
 width: 80%;
 text-align: center;
 margin: 10px auto;
}
#pdfResourceWrap {
 float: right;
 margin: 0 auto;
 padding: 20px 0;
 width: 80%;
 height: auto;
}
.pdfResource {
 width: 48%;
 height: auto;
 display: inline-block;
 vertical-align: top;
 margin: 15px 1%;
 padding: 5px 0;
 text-align: center;
 -webkit-transition: all .45s ease;transition: all .45s ease;
}
.pdfResource:hover {
 background: gray;
 -webkit-transition: all .45s ease;transition: all .45s ease;
}
.pdfResource img {
 width: 50px;
 height: auto;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
.resourceTitle {
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 font-size: .8rem;
 letter-spacing: .1rem;
 color: #F2F2F2;
 margin-top: 5px;
 line-height: 1.4em;
 padding: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<div id="pdfBannerRight">
      <div id="pdfBannerRightCont">
       <h3 id="resourceWrapTitle">Resources</h3>
       <div id="pdfResourceWrap">
        
        <div id="resourceCont">
         <a href="#" class="pdfResource">
          <img src="https://imagineacademy.microsoft.com/content/images/microsoft-img.png" alt="Img 1">
          <h4 class="resourceTitle">Img 1</h4>
         </a><a href="#" class="pdfResource">
          <img src="https://imagineacademy.microsoft.com/content/images/microsoft-img.png" alt="Img2">
          <h4 class="resourceTitle">Img 2</h4>
         </a>
        </div>
       </div>
     </div>
```